# Wait for System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLineAsync

Tags: optimization, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I want to wait for a line to be read, but only for so long before timing out.  This is what I came up with.  Is there a better way to do it?

```
Dim reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(pipe)

Dim nextCommand = Await New Func(Of Task(Of String))(
    Function()
        Dim t = reader.ReadLineAsync()
        If (Not t.Wait(2000)) Then Throw New MyTimeoutExeption()
        Return t
    End Function).Invoke()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For operations that don't support cancellation themselves, You can combine [`Task.WhenAny()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194796) with [`Task.Delay()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194873):

```
Async Function TryAwait(Of T)(target As Task(Of T), delay as Integer) As Task(Of T)
    Dim completed = Await Task.WhenAny(target, Task.Delay(delay))
    If completed Is target Then
        Return Await target
    End If

    Throw New TimeoutException()
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim nextCommand = Await TryAwait(reader.ReadLineAsync(), 2000)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify one thing?  `Return Await target` won't actually continue to await, since it's already completed, right?  Is its purpose there only to make sure a `Task(Of T)` is returned?

Comment: @roryap Yeah. And also to make sure exceptions from `target` are propagated.

Comment: What about Timeout?